# Spring Data Mongo @Transactional annotation is not considering a transaction : allowing partial commit

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, grpc-java

I am using grpc call with mongo db to do multiple transactions in a single call. I am new to spring data mongo and grpc, so a bit of guidance is expecting

Our protobuf looks something like below

```
service MongoStoreService {


  rpc ExecuteTransaction(ExecuteTransactionRequest) returns (ExecuteTransactionResponse);
}



message GetRequest {
  string name = 1 ;

}


message GetResponse {
  Document document = 1;
}


message CreateRequest {

  string parent = 1 ;
  Document document = 2;
}


message CreateResponse {
  Document document = 1;
}


message UpdateRequest {

  Document document = 1;

  
}


message UpdateResponse {
 
  Document document = 1;
}


message DeleteRequest {

  string name = 1 ;
}


message DeleteResponse {

  Document document = 1;
}



message ExecuteTransactionRequest {
  
  repeated DocumentOperationRequest document_operation_requests = 1;
}


message ExecuteTransactionResponse {
 
  repeated DocumentOperationResponse document_operation_responses = 1;
}


message DocumentOperationRequest {

  oneof request {
    CreateRequest create_request = 1;

    GetRequest get_request = 2;

    UpdateRequest update_request = 3;

    DeleteRequest delete_request = 4;
  }
}


message DocumentOperationResponse {

  oneof response {
    CreateResponse create_response = 1;

    GetResponse get_response = 2;

    UpdateResponse update_response = 3;

    DeleteResponse delete_response = 4;
  }
}
```

We want to achieve the ACID property on ExecuteTransactionRequest for multiple operations

Grpc controller code

```
@Override
    public void executeTransaction(ExecuteTransactionRequest request,
                                   StreamObserver<ExecuteTransactionResponse> responseObserver){
        ExecuteTransactionResponse response;
        logger.info("Transaction request received with documents {}", request.getDocumentOperationRequestsList());
        try{
            response = documentService.executeTransactions(request);
            responseObserver.onNext(response);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("exception occurred while executing Transactions {}", e.getErrorMessage());
            responseObserver.onError(StatusProto.toStatusRuntimeException(ErrorCodeTransformer.grpcErrorResponse(e)));
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }
```

This is MongoDBServiceImpl code for above

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public ExecuteTransactionResponse executeTransactions(ExecuteTransactionRequest request)  {
        List<DocumentOperationRequest> documentOperationRequestList = request.getDocumentOperationRequestsList();
        logger.info("Transaction request received with documents");
        List<DocumentOperationResponse>  documentOperationResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        DocumentOperationResponse documentOperationResponse;

        try {
            for (DocumentOperationRequest documentOperationRequest : documentOperationRequestList) {
                switch (documentOperationRequest.getRequestCase()) {
                    case GET_REQUEST:
                        documentOperationResponse = DocumentOperationResponse.newBuilder()
                                        .setGetResponse(getDocument(documentOperationRequest.getGetRequest()))
                                .build();
                        documentOperationResponseList.add(documentOperationResponse);
                        break;
                    case CREATE_REQUEST:
                        documentOperationResponse = DocumentOperationResponse.newBuilder()
                                .setCreateResponse(createDocument(documentOperationRequest.getCreateRequest()))
                                .build();
                        documentOperationResponseList.add(documentOperationResponse);
                        break;
                    case DELETE_REQUEST:
                        documentOperationResponse = DocumentOperationResponse.newBuilder()
                                .setDeleteResponse(deleteDocument(documentOperationRequest.getDeleteRequest()))
                                .build();
                        documentOperationResponseList.add(documentOperationResponse);
                        break;
                    case UPDATE_REQUEST:
                        documentOperationResponse = DocumentOperationResponse.newBuilder()
                                .setUpdateResponse(updateDocument(documentOperationRequest.getUpdateRequest()))
                                .build();
                        documentOperationResponseList.add(documentOperationResponse);
                        break;
                }

            }

            ExecuteTransactionResponse executeTransactionResponse = ExecuteTransactionResponse.newBuilder()
                .addAllDocumentOperationResponses(documentOperationResponseList)
                .build();
            return executeTransactionResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("exception occurred while executing transactions {}", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I came to know from few of the spark data mongo framework documentation that @Transactional annotation should take care the ACID property. But I am seeing that even if sometimes there is any failure the partial operations were committed on db.

When I am sending following message on local grpc call, it is working as expected:

```
{
  "document_operation_requests": [
    {
      "create_document_request": {
        "document": {
          
        },
        "parent": "collection_01"
      }
      ,
      
      "delete_document_request": {
        
      
    }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Now say if there is a multiple set of operations, that time partial commit is allowing(below payload)

```
{
  "document_operation_requests": [
    {
      "create_document_request": {
        "document": {
          
        },
        "parent": "collection_01"
      }
      
      
     
    },
{ "delete_document_request": {
        
      
    }}
    
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me why list of operations for the 2nd payload is considered as independent? How can I fix this?